# C# error: Type 'x' already defines a member called 'y' with the same parameter types

Tags: c#

On [Visual C# Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_C.23_Express), I get the following error with the code below:

> 'Type 'myComponent.SettingsComponent' already defines a member called 'SolveInstance' with the same parameter types'

But I only used `SolveInstance` there. What am I doing wrong and how would I be able to solve this on my own next time?

```
namespace myComponent
{
    public class SettingsComponent : GH_Component
    {
        protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
        {
        }

        protected override void  RegisterOutputParams(GH_Component.GH_OutputParamManager pManager)
        {
        }

        protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
        {
            if (m_settings == null)
            {
                AddRuntimeMessage(warning, "You must declare some valid settings");
                return;
            }
            DA.SetData(0, m_settings);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is GH_Component.SolveInstance virtual/abstract?

Comment: Is it the actual class? isn't there a partial keyword on the class? Can you put more code ?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution?

Comment: @ananthonline GH_Component.SolveInstance is abstract, syntax: protected abstract void SolveInstance(
 IGH_DataAccess DA
) I have changed it thanks, still same issue though

Comment: @SteveB sorry what is a 'partial keyword'? There are more methods in the class but not sure how much you want me to paste? the full function is GH_Component.SolveInstance Method

Comment: Your current edit makes no sense. SettingsComponent.SolveInstance CANNOT be abstract and define a body. I am not sure the problem here is as deep as it looks. Please post the current method declarations from both GH_Component AND SettingsComponent.

Comment: @ananthonline, method declaration for GH_Component: public abstract class GH_Component : GH_ActiveObject, 
 IGH_Component
method declaration for SettingComponent: public class SettingsComponent : GH_Component, is that what you mean? Sorry if I am getting it wrong

Comment: @arthurmani - This question is incomplete and requires more information in order to be solved. As others have suggested, showing `GH_Component` is going to constitute that missing information. If you do not want to post that code, post an example which produces the same error.

Comment: @TravisJ the problem is that GH_Component is part of the Kernel so I cannot see it...

Comment: @TravisJ I have added a bit of code, I cannot delete the other SolveInstance as it is needed for the class to determine the inputs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you have two instances of

```
protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
```

in your example class, one with an empty body and one with code.

Comment: Thanks @JeffCuscutis I merged the two instances and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Try to find all occurences of SolveInstance in the project. You will possibly find another definition of this method in a .designer.cs file. They are autogenerated and sometimes they cause duplicity problems.

Comment: Wouldn't `SettingsComponent` above be a partial class in that case?

Comment: Maybe it used to be partial. I guess that removing a piece of code that caused code-autogeneration doesn't revert this autogeneration. But I am not 100% sure of this.